# Best webserver with minimum resource

Tags: php, apache, nginx

Now i am using apache2, but i heard about engine-x (nginx) is pretty fast and with low hardware consumption. If the feedback is good enough than my lamp environment will be changed in lxmp.

Comment: See this article : http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2011/11/a-faster-web-server-ripping-out-apache-for-nginx.ars?comments=1#comments-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nginx for staic content and apache2 for php.